# Getting output that results from ajax error

Tags: django

I've got an ajax view that works fine locally, but on my live, production server, I believe that there is an error within the view. When developing locally, this error will automatically print to my console (command prompt), and I can evaluation the problem. In production, I'm not sure how to capture this error. Django doesn't throw a hard error on ajax problems, so I'm not sure that logging will work. For problems with views that are dedicated to ajax requests, I normally rely on that error message that pops up in my console (command prompt).

Is there a way that I can capture this error that is happening my my production environment on my view that is dedicated to an ajax request?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think "Django doesn't throw a hard error on ajax problems"? Django makes no distinction between Ajax and non Ajax requests.

Comment: Sorry, I mean when there is a problem within a view that only contains logic under    if request.is_ajax():, it seems like the error doesn't get thrown in the browser, but rather, within the console.

Comment: If Django is returning an error response you can see it in the browsers developer tools, eg in the Network tab

Comment: Within the Network tab, when I click on the url of the view that has the ajax, it just says "Failed to load response data"

Comment: Can you share the error and the code you feel is causing issue

Comment: I'd rather not. It's a huge view and it works 100% in my dev environment. this is something that I need to see the error on and should be able to resolve myself. thanks though.